# php query where a word like and skip before words

Tags: php, mysql

php script query out put is 
     "some word STAR some other words", I want remove all workd before "Star". I need all other words after "Star".

I using php script output from a mysql file

Comment: > insert boilerplate "what have you tried so far?" comment here <

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$arrayStr = explode('STAR', 'some word STAR some other words');
echo $arrayStr[1];
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/DKH7ohEV)

---

Some documentation:

[**php.net explode() function**](https://www.php.net/explode)

Comment: Though this works, I dont recommend using array functions which can be done with string functions. String-functions are often WAY faster and use less resources. Also, this will have a problem when STAR occers twice, but the TS didnt specify that, so no downvoting :)

Comment: Thank you for your clarifications about code speed. +1 so others will give attention to it

Comment: ITs work good.. But $one = "START"; $two = "some word STAR some other words"; $arrayStr = explode('$one', '$two');
echo $arrayStr[1]; Not work

Comment: Double quotes or no quotes at all.

Comment: Anyway as Martijin suggested the explode function is slower than the one in the other exapmple, even if it works. Keep this in mind.

Answer (score 2):

```
$newStr = substr_replace($str, '', 0, strpos($str,"STAR"));
```

Where $str is a variable with a string, eg: "some word STAR some other words"